Interpretation of a log-scale experience curve in The Innovator's Dilemma
I'm currently reading The Innovator's Dilemma by Clayton Christensen and I came across the following statement:
Figure 1.3 shows that the slope of the industry’s experience curve (which correlates the cumulative
number of terabytes (one thousand gigabytes) of disk storage capacity shipped in the industry’s history
to the constant-dollar price per megabyte of memory) was 53 percent—meaning that with each
doubling of cumulative terabytes shipped, cost per megabyte fell to 53 percent of its former level. This
is a much steeper rate of price decline than the 70 percent slope observed in the markets for most other
microelectronics products. The price per megabyte has declined at about 5 percent per quarter for more
than twenty years. 

I would have included an image of the figure in question but I'm not allowed to yet by Stack Exchange. That said, the image is basically a 2D graph of x > 0, y > 0 where the x and y axes are log scaled. The x axis represents the number of terabytes shipped on a given year and the y axis represents the price per megabyte. It then has some points plotted on it and a line fit to them. The line slants diagonally downward from the y axis and is meant to show that as the value of x increases the value of y decreases.
The author states in the quoted passage that a slope of 0.53 (presumably the author means -0.53 since the line slants downwards?) means that when x doubles y decreases by 53%. Is this true? I don't see how this works since according to my calculations, the decrease should actually by ~30%.
If the equation for the line on log scale is:
$logy = -.53logx + c$
Since $log2x = logx + log2$, doubling x for the equation above results in
$\log y -.53\log 2 = -.53\log 2x + c$
$\log y/2^{.53} = -.53\log 2x + c$
And since $2^{.53} \approx 1.44$, we end up getting $y * 1/1.44$ which is $y * 0.7$ approximately.
